# Running command on substring of every file

Tags: bash

Let's say I've some files like:

```
samplea.txt
sampleb.txt
samplec.txt
```

And I want to run some command with this form:

```
./cmd -foo a.xml -bar samplea.txt
```

First I've tried to

```
for file in "./*.txt"
do
    echo -e $file
done
```

But this way it will print every file in a straight line. By trying:

```
echo -e $file\n
```

It does not produce the expected (single line for each file).
Couldn't even pass through the first part of the problem, that would be running a command on each file (which it could be achieved by find (...) -exec), but what i really wanted to do was extract a substring of each name.

Doing:

```
echo ${file:1}
```

won't work since I could only do so after splitting the filenames, to get the "a","b","c" from each one.

I'm sorry if it sounds confusing, but it's my first bash script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not quote the wildcard expression. You can use parameter expansion to remove parts of a string:

```
for file in sample*.txt ; do
    part=${file#sample}                 # Remove "sample" at the beginning.
    part=${part%.txt}                   # Remove ".txt" at the end.
    ./cmd -foo "$part".xml -bar "$file"
done
```